# Offline persisting storage in Sencha mobile app

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2, persistence, local-storage

I am new to mobile app development. I am creating cross-platform app using Sencha + Phonegap. My goal is to store user-written text in mobile (offline storage) and some other text data related to it, that would persist even if mobile restarts, which would be then uploaded to server, once mobile has connection.

According to this http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy
Sencha provides 2 client side storages.

```
LocalStorageProxy - saves its data to localStorage if the browser supports it
MemoryProxy - holds data in memory only, any data is lost when the page is refreshed
```

MemoryProxy is out of question. And LocalStorage uses HTML5 storage and I dont believe that that lasts after reboot.

So what I need is some kind of database, which will be accessible from Sencha, on both Android and IOS, in offline mode. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Can you give some feedback on my answer? Was it useful?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, thank you for answer. However I didn't manage to implement it yet (will happen sometime next week). I will let you know. But so far I think that was the missing puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, `localStorage` is persistent between applications restarts and application reboots. Are you maybe confusing it with `sessionStorage`? As far as I know, data will be wiped out only if the user actively clears application data (for example on Android from the application menu).

Anyway, since you are using Cordova/Phonegap, you have these [Storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) options:

- **localStorage**, key/value persistent storage ([support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage))
- **WebSQL**, offers more full-featured database tables accessed via SQL queries (Android, BlackBerry 10, iOS, Tizen).
- **IndexedDB**, more features than LocalStorage but fewer than WebSQL (only Windows Phone and Blackberry).

Plus you could use:

- [**filesystem**](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) Cordova Api

Comment: I finally managed to implement it. localStarage is working well. I read somewhere that application should not rely on localStorage, where it stores all of its data, so I switched to filesystem, which also works well. Everything is persistent. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The localstorage is persistent.
For example in android the localstorage data can only be deleted if the app deletes it, or the app is erased, or if the user goes to the setting and erases the app data for that one particular app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is persistent. for better implementation you can refer this
:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/creating-an-online-offline-proxy-in-sencha-touch